# Play a password protected .m3u audio stream with AVPlayer or similar

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I need to play a password protected `.m3u` audio stream within an iOS app. Previously I've had this working with `AVPlayer` for an identical non-password protected stream:

`self.player = AVPlayer.playerWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://<server-here>:<port-here>/live.m3u")!) as! AVPlayer
self.player.play()`

However it appears at first glance that `AVPlayer` does not support any kind of authentication.

By putting a proxy on the connection when using other clients which support password protected streams, I can see a request is made to stream, which fails with a 401. The same request is made with the authentication details in the HTTP header and then the stream request succeeds. So it's pretty basic HTTP authentication going on and nothing particularly fancy.

Does anyone know of a way of achieving this using `AVFoundation`, or do I have to resort to a low level 3rd party streaming library to achieve this?